# Broadcastreceiver App Crash

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am new to Android Programming and I am trying to learn how to download an image in the backgroud using Broadcast receiver. Now everytime I run the app, the app crashes. I kept trying so much, but in vain . I hope you guys can help me.

**This is the code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button go, kill;

public static ProgressBar progressBar1, progressBar2, progressBar3, progressBar4, progressBar5;

public static ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4, imageView5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
    kill = (Button) findViewById(R.id.killButton);

    progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    progressBar3 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
    progressBar4 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar4);
    progressBar5 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar5);

    imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageView5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(getString(R.string.downloaded));
    registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, intentFilter);

    go.setOnClickListener(this);
    kill.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.goButton:

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Interaction.class);
            startService(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.killButton:

            finish();
            break;

    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(downloadReceiver);
}

private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
};


}
```

**Interaction**

```
public class Interaction extends Service {

final class MyThreadClass implements Runnable{

    int service_id;
    MyThreadClass(int service_id){

        this.service_id = service_id;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // new
        MainActivity.imageView1.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(getString(R.string.link1)));
        MainActivity.imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getString(R.string.downloaded));
        sendBroadcast(intent1);

        stopSelf(service_id);

    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(this,"Downloading Photos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new MyThreadClass(startId));
    thread.start();
    return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src){

    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;

    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }

}

}
```

This is the logcat:

--------- beginning of crash

```
10-23 10:50:15.322 2568-3873/ziad.example.com.downloadapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
                                                                            Process: ziad.example.com.downloadapp, PID: 2568
                                                                            android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6891)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1048)
                                                                                at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                                at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                                at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                                at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                                at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                                at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
                                                                                at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                                at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:529)
                                                                                at android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(ImageView.java:659)
                                                                                at ziad.example.com.downloadapp.Interaction$MyThreadClass.run(Interaction.java:39)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: share error logcat...

Comment: error log..............  ?

Comment: Are u registering the receiver  in manifest, plz check.

Comment: I have edited the post and added the logcat.

I am not registering the receiver in the manifest, as I don't have a separate class for the BroadcastReceiver

Comment: You cannot access UI components from threads other than the main or UI thread but you are doing that in MyThreadClass in run method, that is what the error is about.

Comment: Could you please tell how to fix that?

Comment: try using Glide library. this will compact your code to few lines.

Comment: can you tell me what happens when you image is being downloaded and your activity got destroyed? NPE. 

Do not use activity's view in service and do ever make View as static object as it leads to memory leak.

Comment: It tells me, your app has been stopped. Then when I reopen the App I find that the image is there and 1 progressbar has disappeared.
If I make the imageView not static, how can I access it from other classes?